# How can I import an image into my Spring project?

Tags: java, css, spring

For a university project, we've been asked to create a vendor website that does x y z. For this I have been given the task of designing the actual front-end and I was wondering if the background image I wish to use for the website could just be easily imported into a resource folder or some such in my project?

I've looked about and have seen there are a few methods but I feel like surely there must be some way of just importing the image and saving it in my project files somewhere to be referenced by my stylesheet.

Using spring's Import function doesn't allow me to import .jpegs only other projects or .zip's.

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm just feeling a bit stumped by this!

Comment: You can put images in the same folder as your html files.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your images inside the webapp folder by creating a new folder called images like below.

`/src/main/webapp/images`

You need to simply place all your front-end stuff inside the webapp folder.When it comes to importing images there is nothing to be worried. Just copy your image and paste it in to your images folder.Then give the image path to display the image in the front-end.

Comment: Thankyou! I assume its alright to do do this in the stylesheet?

background-image: (path here);

Comment: This didn't end up working unfortunately. I took advice of the comment on the post by Erik though and copied the image straight into my static resources file and it worked!

Comment: @Sam Thrower In my opinion It's better to put your front-end stuff inside the webapp. The problem that this didn't work, probably because you might not have been given a valid image path to the front-end.